# Getstream individual notifications for different reaction types?

Tags: getstream-io

As far as I can tell, and from a couple of small experiments, all reactions on an activity are returned together as part of an activity (or can an activity be given with only a subset of reactions?)  Also, the seen/read fields are also set for the activity, not for individual reactions.  Based on this, granular notifications for reactions like "John liked your post" and "Jane commented on your post" with accurate seen/read fields for each individual reaction are not possible (unless you make comments an activity instead of a reaction).

Is there a recommended way to implement reactions and notifications that allows for the same features Facebook has?

Answer (score 0):

Reactions are indeed returned as part of the activity, but they are mapped by the reaction kind. (`like`, `love` etc).

As for the notifications, instead of using reactions, you can use activities to achieve this:

```
activity = {
  "actor": "john:1",
  "verb": "like",
  "object": "post:1"
}
```

This, in combination with using notification feeds should get you the desired result.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Is it a good idea to use a combination, to store it both as a reaction and an activity, so it's easier to get the reactions related to the activity?

Comment: It seems a little like using a tool not the way it was designed since reactions are built-in to the stream framework.  I'm a little concerned about the efficiency of having every reaction as an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it wasn't available at the time you wrote the post, but now you can notify people about a reaction using the `targetFeed` prop as explained in the doc https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/php/reactions_read_feeds/#notify-other-feeds